# How to retrieve first value for a column in Oracle database?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have written a query and here below I mentioned.

```
    SELECT P.PERSON_ID,
                P.BIRTH_DATE,
                P.GENDER_CODE,
                LISTAGG(R.RACE_CODE, ',') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY R.RACE_CODE) AS RACE_CODE,
                P.HISPANIC_LATINO_CODE,
                C.CLINICALLY_DIAGNOSED_CODE,
                LISTAGG(C.CHARACTERISTIC_CODE, ',') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY C.CHARACTERISTIC_CODE) AS CHARA_CODES,
                P.PREV_ADOPTED_CODE,
                P.AGE_ADOPTED,
                PE.REMOVED_DATE
  FROM PERSON P
  LEFT OUTER JOIN RACE R
    ON P.PERSON_ID = R.PERSON_ID
  LEFT OUTER JOIN CHARACTERISTIC C
    ON C.PERSON_ID = P.PERSON_ID
  LEFT OUTER JOIN PLACEMENT_EPISODE PE
    ON P.PERSON_ID = PE.CHILD_ID
 GROUP BY P.PERSON_ID,
          P.BIRTH_DATE,
          P.GENDER_CODE,
          P.HISPANIC_LATINO_CODE,
          C.CLINICALLY_DIAGNOSED_CODE,
          P.PREV_ADOPTED_CODE,
          P.AGE_ADOPTED,
          PE.REMOVED_DATE
```

Here, I want to change my query so that it will retrieve only first value for pe.removed_date.

I read about FIRST() function [here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_first.asp). But I am not able to change my query to use FIRST() function.

Suppose PERSON table holds person_id's 1,2,3... And PLACEMENT_EPISODE holds values like:

```
person_id   removed_date
   1          d1_1
   2          d2_1
   1          d1_2
   3          d3_1
   2          d2_2
   1          d1_3
```

So i want:

```
 person_id           removed_date
  1            d1_1
  2            d2_1
  3            d3_1
```

child_id from PLACEMENT_EPISODE table is foreign key references Primary key person_id from PERSON table.

Comment: You mean you want to restrict the output to one row based on the order of `pe.removed_date`?

Comment: For one person there will be many removed_date in placement_episode table. I want to get first value of removed_date from placement_episode table for a person

Comment: You have not answered my question, what is your desired output. Post the input and desired output. Also, mention the Oracle version.

Comment: @LalitKumarB I added some description in my question. I hope you will get it.

Comment: @Rushikesh: it does not make sense to speak about the "first" value in a column if you do not have define an ORDER BY clause in your statement. So do you want define an order or do you want an arbitrary sleceted colulumn value be  displayed?

Comment: No need for SELECT DISTINCT here, because the GROUP BY returns no duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY..` to get order number by specified clause. Wrap your statement with `select * from` Then use that order number in its where clause like in this SQL:

```
select * from ( 
 SELECT         P.PERSON_ID,
                P.BIRTH_DATE,
                P.GENDER_CODE,
                LISTAGG(R.RACE_CODE, ',') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY R.RACE_CODE) AS RACE_CODE,
                P.HISPANIC_LATINO_CODE,
                C.CLINICALLY_DIAGNOSED_CODE,
                LISTAGG(C.CHARACTERISTIC_CODE, ',') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY C.CHARACTERISTIC_CODE) AS CHARA_CODES,
                P.PREV_ADOPTED_CODE,
                P.AGE_ADOPTED,
                PE.REMOVED_DATE,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY P.PERSON_ID ORDER BY PE.REMOVED_DATE ASC) AS order_num
  FROM PERSON P
  LEFT OUTER JOIN RACE R
    ON P.PERSON_ID = R.PERSON_ID
  LEFT OUTER JOIN CHARACTERISTIC C
    ON C.PERSON_ID = P.PERSON_ID
  LEFT OUTER JOIN PLACEMENT_EPISODE PE
    ON P.PERSON_ID = PE.CHILD_ID
 GROUP BY P.PERSON_ID,
          P.BIRTH_DATE,
          P.GENDER_CODE,
          P.HISPANIC_LATINO_CODE,
          C.CLINICALLY_DIAGNOSED_CODE,
          P.PREV_ADOPTED_CODE,
          P.AGE_ADOPTED,
          PE.REMOVED_DATE
) WHERE order_num=1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want just a first selected row you can use rownum.

```
SELECT DISTINCT P.PERSON_ID,
                P.BIRTH_DATE,
                P.GENDER_CODE,
                LISTAGG(R.RACE_CODE, ',') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY R.RACE_CODE) AS RACE_CODE,
                P.HISPANIC_LATINO_CODE,
                C.CLINICALLY_DIAGNOSED_CODE,
                LISTAGG(C.CHARACTERISTIC_CODE, ',') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY C.CHARACTERISTIC_CODE) AS CHARA_CODES,
                P.PREV_ADOPTED_CODE,
                P.AGE_ADOPTED,
                PE.REMOVED_DATE
  FROM PERSON P
  LEFT OUTER JOIN RACE R
    ON P.PERSON_ID = R.PERSON_ID
  LEFT OUTER JOIN CHARACTERISTIC C
    ON C.PERSON_ID = P.PERSON_ID
  LEFT OUTER JOIN PLACEMENT_EPISODE PE
    ON P.PERSON_ID = PE.CHILD_ID
 WHERE ROWNUM = 1;
 GROUP BY P.PERSON_ID,
          P.BIRTH_DATE,
          P.GENDER_CODE,
          P.HISPANIC_LATINO_CODE,
          C.CLINICALLY_DIAGNOSED_CODE,
          P.PREV_ADOPTED_CODE,
          P.AGE_ADOPTED,
          PE.REMOVED_DATE
```

Comment: GROUP BY clause should be after where clause. And I want to retrieve first value for that particular column. ROWNUM = 1 will give me first row of entire result set

Comment: "SELECT *  FROM ()a where rownum=1"  Inside barckets add your query. I tnink not issue.

Comment: It is not solution for my question. SO I can't accept your answer

Comment: @MukeshKalgude That would give just *one random* row.